# Trouble using Remix to deploy to BSC TestNet

Tags: contract-development, contract-deployment

Hey yall im getting this error when trying to deploy to smartchain testnet

> Gas estimation failed Close Gas estimation errored with the following
> message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do
> you want to force sending? Internal JSON-RPC error. { "code": -32000,
> "message": "gas required exceeds allowance (30000000) or always
> failing transaction" }

I click okay and accept the transaction anyway but it fails and gives me:

> "false Transaction mined but execution failed"

Im deploying the contract MADToken - MADToken.sol
there are also these other contracts to choose from but none of them carry the appropriate ABI or Bytecode for properly verifying the contract once its on BSC.

Contract: [MADToken GitHub](https://github.com/strainzeh/MADToken/blob/main/MADToken.sol)

Comment: The problem is obviously in the constructor. Did you try debugging it? I see in the constructor harcoded addresses did you check if the address were valid contracts on testnet?

Answer (score 0):

you need to connect to bsc test network shown here
https://dapp-world.com/blogs/01/how-to-connect-metamask-to-binance-smart-chainbsc--1618137142422

Then from remix's deploy section
choose Web3 Provider and then deploy

Hope it works